# Check info about thickness of vertex point

Tags: vertices

Is there a way to check the statistic info of a vertex point in grease pencil? If I change the thickness of a vertex point in sculpt mode or with alt s in edit mode, I want to know exactly how much thicker or thinner it gets and I want to be able to check it anytime so that I don't need to remember what changes I have done.